# VScode container makes core.XXXXXX files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the VScode as docker container on my k8s clusters.
Sometimes the file "core.XXXXXX" which is over 4GB is made but I don't know why.
When I "cat" this file, the content looks like logs of debugging.
And when I click this file at the vscode web-browser, the connection died. (hang infinitely)

I want to configure out who made this dump file and not to be made.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I got to know...!!
The files starting with core.XXXXX are generated by abrt-hook-ccpp whenever the container is killed by the kubelet with OOM.

With the configuration file (ulimit -c), it generates the core.XXXX files whenever any processes are killed by SIGSEGV.